# In Vim, how to move text to be edited to the middle of the window?

Tags: vim, gvim

Is it possible to have the text in a (g)Vim window in the middle?
This is the default: [image: default]
And this is what I would like to achieve (mockup created with gimp): [image: solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have empty windows on the left and right of the one you're editing:

```
:leftabove vnew
:wincmd l
:vnew
:wincmd h
```

To hide the dividers and tildes use the `:highlight` command and the `VertSplit/NonText` highlight groups. Note that hiding `NonText` also hides `list` characters, see `:help 'list'`.

So to hide dividers and the tildes in `gvim` you could do the following:

```
:highlight VertSplit guifg=bg guibg=bg
:highlight NonText   guifg=bg
```

Comment: That could work. I suppose its not possible to hide the dividers?

Comment: @Psirus: added some highlight commands that hide the dividers and the tildes.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! BTW, small typo in last line (guifb vs guifg).

Answer (score 6):

There are plugins that create empty padding windows and turn off all the decorations; usually, they provide a command to toggle this view on/off:

- [VimRoom](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/)
- [DistractFree - An WriteRoom/DarkRoom/OmniWrite like plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4357)

Comment: That sounds like the way to go. I'll investigate these later today.

Answer (score 0):

```
:set foldcolumn=3          # replace with left border width you want
:set foldmethod=manual
```

// from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10778132/286595)